# A task/job scheduling problem

Tags: algorithm, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, scheduler

I have a task/job scheduling problem and I would like to find preferably efficient algorithms to solve it.

Let's say there are some workers. Every worker is able to do a different set of tasks/jobs. The following example may make it clear:

```
  Worker A (can do): T2, T3
  Worker B         : T1, T3, T4
  Worker C         : T3, T5
```

Now we have a list of tasks which must be done. For example, the list is something like: T1, T3, T5

There's some constraints:

1. Each task must be taken by one worker
2. Several tasks can be taken concurrently
3. But a worker can do only one task at the same time. (He/she is not available until finish the task)

For the above example, we may have a schedule like this:

```
  T1 --> Worker B
  T3 --> Worker C   T5 --> Worker C
```

As you may noticed, the above schedule is not optimal. Because T5 has to wait worker C to finish T3. The following solution is better:

```
  T1 --> Worker B
  T3 --> Worker A
  T5 --> Worker C
```

Because there's no wait.

Now suppose that I know the the worker-tasks matrix (what worker can do what tasks). **The tasks will come one by one, but don't know what it will be.** I am asked to design a scheduler that automatically find an idle worker for every coming task. And when finally all the tasks are done, there's a minimum waiting time.

So I need an algorithm for this scheduler. I don't want to reinvent the wheel if the perfect wheel already exists.  Can any one help?

Thanks.

Comment: If you cannot look into the future, I'd guess that sending the tasks as they come in to the worker with the _fewest_ abilities would leave the most possibilities open for the future. Are the workers humans who have some expectation of getting work eventually? Or are the workers computers and they don't care if they get work or not?

Comment: To me it sounds like the "automatically find an idle worker for every coming task", "don't know what it will be" and "minimum waiting time" are all at odds with each other. If you can't plan, you can't optimize.

Comment: What if there is no idle worker, how do you intend to deal with that? Just queue them up?

Comment: Also, are all the workers equally suited for all the tasks? In other words, could it be that Worker A is better suited for T1 type tasks than the other workers?

Comment: @Lasse: that was my first thought as well, rather than using a boolean condition, a better modeling would associate a speed of execution to a given type of task for each worker.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for a "Bin Packing" algorithm -

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing

The general bin packing problem, very similar to what you phrased, is NP-Hard so you can forget about an optimal solution if your input size is more than trivial.

What you can find is a solution that is guaranteed not to be too far from the optimal solution, usually my some factor. That wikipedia article is a good place to start.

Comment: Actually this isn't bin packing, this is a job shop scheduling problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_Shop_Scheduling

Answer (score 3):

Algorithms operating on input that is not known upfront but is coming in "as you go" are called [on-line algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm). They are only sub-optimal, naturally. They are measured by being worse than the optimal algorithm not more than by a constant factor (e.g. if the best solution (which is not on-line, i.e. has the whole input upfront) takes X steps, your on-line one should take not more than k*X steps, the smaller the k the better of course).

In your case the requirement is not clear - "minimum waiting time" compared to what?

One idea that may help you is to pick up an available worker with the **smallest** task list, saving the more "diverse" workers for future tasks.